# How in Jenkins to trigger two jobs with different property files as parameters and run them in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am new to Jenkins, I need to run a job, say Job_B, twice and parallel, with 2 different property files (name of the file is same, but content is different), so that one of the run will consume one property file while the other run will consume the other property file.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried passing two propery files location in configuration matrix>> user defined matrix for the job

Answer (score 0):

This very much possible to trigger concurrent jobs and parameterized build plugin.also there are numerous way you can achieve it.

Way 1:
To enable the concurrent jobs:

1. enable "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" in configure job window.
2. make parameterized build:
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Way 2:

you can trigger job with different parameters using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Is there a way apart from parameterized build, as there are lot of property files to be passed and manually passing is taking a lot of time.

Comment: need not to pass it manaually create a parent job who reads and trigger multiple jobs. or try other option

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the `jenkins-workflow` tag, perhaps by mistake, I will answer according to that: using the Workflow plugin, and inlining all this logic into one job, you would have full flexibility to load as many property files as you wish from whatever sources, and run subsequent build steps in parallel (perhaps on different slaves) with the corresponding properties. (The question is a bit too vague for a code sample.)